# cytosape setup for off-line use?

Tags: cytoscape

Is there a preferred way to setup cytoscape for off-line use?  My little network of lab equipment isn't connected to the Internet.  I have version 3.9.1 (linux) that seems to be working, but get Java complaints because it's trying to go to the Internet and can't.  If there are configuration settings I can adjust to make it stop trying to go to the Internet that would be great.  Maybe some kind of cheat-sheet for setting up an off-line installation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On startup, Cytoscape checks to see if there is an update available.  The error should not be fatal and should not impact Cytoscape operations at all.  Are you having problems after it starts up?

Comment: It does seem to work.  I was just hoping to get rid of the error message and stack dump, if possible.